# How to do imports in python?

Tags: python, import

I did some websearch, but all I found was **frustration**.

I have a project in a directory (lets call it) "projectdir", in which I have "main.py".
In projectdir I have a subdirectory called "otherstuff", In which I have "foo.py".

How do I import foo.py, so I can use its contents in main.py, without doing much of the work that python designers/implementors should have, and without relying on boilerplate files?

Or is that impossible in python?

Comment: `from otherstuff import foo`?

Comment: @BrtH: and then?: from otherstuff from foo import MyClass ?

Comment: sorry, I was just angry about python being such a ****** language. I had to put it out there. Trying to push it anything beyond a couple files and couple 100 lines, and one has to introduce uglier boilerplate than what c++ has and even do what the language should automatically.

Comment: I've no idea what "boilerplate" you think you need. I regularly work with projects with many many files each of several hundred lines, and have never needed "boilerplate". But if you don't like Python, don't use it: no point getting angry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: import a module from a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a `__init__.py` file in otherstuff subdirectory, to mark it as a package. After, you can import your module using:

```
import subdirectory.foo
```

or

```
from subdirectory import foo
```

The __init__.py file can be empty. There is no other "clean" way to achieve that in python.

Comment: Not technically true, you can add the folder to the python path, but it's ugly and a bad idea.

Comment: Even if the files in the directory are not a module in a logical sense?

Comment: Hmm, the files don't need to be modules in "logical" sense. The only restriction are that their names end in ".py" and contain executable (interpretable) python code.

Comment: I can "print otherstuff.foo.ASD" but how do I get to "print ASD" ?

Comment: @user1358 You want to do `from otherstuff.foo import ASD`, the `from` syntax tells Python to pull it into the namespace for the module.

Answer (score 3):

you need to include `__init__.py` in your `otherstuff` directory.  This is to tell python to search there for imports.

The python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) explains how the module/package import works.  And is def worth the time reading it, despite its kind of long length

Comment: and then just "import otherstuff.foo" ?

Comment: OK I can "print otherstuff.foo.ASD" but how do I get to "print ASD" ?

Comment: `from otherstuff.foo import ASD`?